# Check whether struct has been initialized or allocated some memory yet

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to make a Linked List. So, I declared a LL data structure as below:

```
typedef struct linkedList
{
    char* word;
    struct linkedList* next;
} linkedList;
```

Now, I declared a global variable representing head of the LL as `linkedList* head = NULL;`

Now, I am surprised that even though I assigned a NULL value to the pointer I am able to get inside the below `while` loop.

```
linkedList* node = head;
while(node != NULL);
{
  //Why I am here when I have not yet malloc'ed head and through global variable initialization my head is NULL
}
```

Because of this I am feeling like I have no way to check if my linked list `head` has been initialized or allocated some memory yet. I cannot check with `node->next` because it will result in segmentation fault error and `node == NULL` is passing!!!

**Please note** that:

1. Question is strictly for C language
2. I do not want to have some other global variable to track whether my linked list `head` has been initialized or allocated some memory yet. I want to do this using my linked list data structure. This is because suppose my shipping my data structure and want that if somebody is trying to delete something and linked list then empty then some meaning full error should be printed/thrown.

Any idea please.

Comment: You have a semicolon at the end of the `while` line, so it is effectively doing nothing. Then the brackets form a standalone block outside the whle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because of this:

```
while(node != NULL);
```

Remove the semi-colon `;`. Otherwise, when compiling, it doesn't know that the block between `{...}` is after the while, and will enter it, regardless of the verification in the `while (...)`.

Comment: And turn on `-Wall` when compiling.  Then you'll get a warning like "while loop has empty body".

Comment: Thanks mate, silly mistake, I had just figured and came to SO for question deletion but you had hit the bull's eye. Now I am not deleting the question but waiting for 8 minutes to be over so that I can accept your answer.

Comment: @hagrawal Yeah, it's always the little things that get you. Happens to everyone :)

Comment: @Schwern I just tried but I didn't get.